# Pygame unable to init?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
```

Here's my error:

> File "Final_Project.py", line 1, in 
>      import pygame, sys   File "/New Folder With Items/pygame.py", line 2, in 
>       pygame.init() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'

Answer (score 3):

You named your file `pygame.py`. By doing so, you created a module named `pygame`.

So you try to call `init` on your own file, not the real pygame library.

Just don't name your file `pygame.py` (or like any other module you want to use, like `sys.py` etc.).

Comment: By naming your file pygame.py, typing "import pygame" is importing itself.  Since it imports itself, it is effectively running its own code infinitely.  It then calls pygame.init(), but your program (which just imported itself) doesn't have an "init" attribute, making it crash.  Name your program something else, and it should work.

Comment: Your question was answered quite a while ago.  If the answer is acceptable, then accept the answer (click the check below the upvote/downvote bar).